# How do i write regular expression for data like 'A,B','C,D' in MVC model

Tags: regex, validation, model-view-controller

As per requirement i want to validate data in single A-Z alphabet then comma then again A-Z alphabet so how can i write regular expression for it.

my valid data would be **A** Or **A,B** means A-Z and a-z are allowed here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is MVC relevant here? The logic to check a string against a regex is the same in any framework. (Though a programming language or platform would be a useful addition to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regular expression you would use:

```
^[A-Z](,[A-Z])?$
```

^ checks for the start of the line.
[A-Z] will match any character between A-Z once.
The parentheses group the contents together.
the ',' will match a literal comma.
The '?' means the preceding group is optional.
The $ will match end of line.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. my possible data would be A or A,B. can you please suggest solution for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah in that case the + plus signs can be removed and optional after the comma. I will update the anwer